# Trying to use netty4-http as https secure client in camel 2.x

Tags: https, apache-camel, netty4

In my blueprint xml I have set...

```
<sslContextParameters id="ssl" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <keyManagers keyPassword="secret">
            <keyStore password="supersecret" resource="c:/esb/cia_keystore.jks"/>
        </keyManagers>
        <trustManagers>
            <keyStore password="supersecret" resource="c:/esb/cia_truststore.jks"/>
        </trustManagers>
    </sslContextParameters>
```

and want to connect to an https server with this .to line.

```
<to id="_to3" uri="netty4-http:https://somesecurehost.com:443/bla-bla-bla/?ssl=true&sslContextParameters=#ssl"/>
```

But in the blueprint I get a red x and the same in "mvn clean install" the following explanation...

```
The reference to entity "sslContextParameters" must end with the ';' delimiter.
```

Checking the camel netty4-http documentation https://camel.apache.org/components/2.x/netty4-http-component.html I see under options sslContextParameters and query parameters I see both SSL and sslContextParameters.  Nothing in the camel netty4-http mentions a ";" in the URI.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

In XML, special characters need an appropriate escape sequence. So any endpoint URIs that have `&` in the query string, should be modified to use the escape sequence `&amp;`.